# Silverlight styles, an old school html style?

Tags: silverlight, styles

I'm looking for some free silverlight styles to play with. I'd ideally like a style which makes a silverlight page's controls (textbox, etc), look as though they came from a html page. Also after some other styles to play with, any good free libraries out there?

thanks

Comment: I had a go at changing the styles of Silverlight controls. I found some code so that I could put the template in a dedicated file and then dynamically set it on the fly later, i.e. I press a button at runtime and the appearance of the controls changes.
  The problem is that you have to have a copy of the whole template to change a bit of it. I changed the default appearance of the combobox, checkbox, radiobutton, textbox and button. I had a page with perhaps 10 controls on it. The resulting .xap file is 500Kb? 
I don't know how big this file should get? Seems a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=themes&f%5B0%5D.Text=Themes) has some themes that you can download and play with.

However trying to make them look like HTML controls is a tall order.  The reason being that HTML doesn't actually define what the controls look like at all.  For example the same HTML for a CheckBox can be rendered in a variety of different ways depending on the browser and the operating system.

Comment: thanks, good point, I should have specified I meant IE (6 ideally)

Comment: @tony:  IE6 on XP or 2000 and Windows Server 2003? the Textbox/Checkbox etc look very different.  Are you refering to the default windows color scheme used by these platforms since their appearance can vary by user choices?  I take it you're not interested on what this app looks like when run on a Mac?

Comment: Correct, IE6 on XP with default colour scheme.
We have an ajax solution that's presently IE6 only (IE8/7 in 'pretend your IE5.5' mode, we need to prettify it and make it cross browser. Clearly that's achievable using standard css but I want to investigate doing it using silverlight. Clearly there are cons (must be installed, potentially larger page sizes, etc) but ...
  I want to replace a page and make it as close as possible to standard html, and have a dropdown to change the styles.

Thanks for the replies